# Tween engine - Tween.to ignores target value

Tags: java, libgdx, tween

I am trying to change the y position of a sprite, the translation works, my problem is that its ignoring my target and goes to one specific point every time, i don't understand why

Sprite Accessor Code:

```
public class SpriteAccessor implements TweenAccessor<Sprite>{
    public static final int ALPHA = 1;
    public static final int POSITION_X = 2;
    public static final int POSITION_Y = 3;

    @Override
    public int getValues(Sprite target, int tweenType, float[] returnValues) {
        switch (tweenType) {
            case ALPHA:
                returnValues[0] = target.getColor().a;
                return 1;

            case POSITION_X:
                returnValues[1] = target.getX();
                return 2;

            case POSITION_Y:
                returnValues[2] = target.getY();
                return 3;

            default:
                return 0;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setValues(Sprite target, int tweenType, float[] newValues) {
        switch (tweenType) {
            case ALPHA:
                target.setColor(1, 1, 1, newValues[0]);
                break;

            case POSITION_X:
                target.setX(newValues[1]);
                break;

            case POSITION_Y:
                target.setY(newValues[2]);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

And the function where i make the translation:

```
private void setupTween() {
        Tween.registerAccessor(Sprite.class, new SpriteAccessor());
        manager = new TweenManager();

        TweenCallback cb = new TweenCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(int type, BaseTween<?> source) {

            }
        };

        Tween.to(menuLogoSprite, SpriteAccessor.POSITION_Y, 2f)
                .target()//any value i put here is ignored
                .ease(TweenEquations.easeInOutQuint)
                .setCallback(cb).setCallbackTriggers(TweenCallback.COMPLETE)
                .start(manager);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you've misunderstood how the TweenAccessor stuff works. In the `getValue()` method you should place values in the `returnValues` array starting at element zero, and the result should be the number of values placed.

This allows you to handle more than one value with a single tween type.

To solve your immediate problem, try this...

```
    switch (tweenType) {
        case ALPHA:
            returnValues[0] = target.getColor().a;
            return 1;

        case POSITION_X:
            returnValues[0] = target.getX();
            return 1;

        case POSITION_Y:
            returnValues[0] = target.getY();
            return 1;

        default:
            return 0;
    }
}

@Override
public void setValues(Sprite target, int tweenType, float[] newValues) {
    switch (tweenType) {
        case ALPHA:
            target.setColor(1, 1, 1, newValues[0]);
            break;

        case POSITION_X:
            target.setX(newValues[0]);
            break;

        case POSITION_Y:
            target.setY(newValues[0]);
            break;
    }
}
```

Caveat - This is from memory and I haven't actually tried your code.

Comment: Thank you! this fixed my problem